# How to kill or suspend a job on global queue running in background in GCD

Tags: multithreading, ios5, ios6, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

I have a background task to download from a webservice which runs in background and i want to suspend it if user navigates to other screens meanwhile.

Here is how i tried to download in background:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

NewsResponseBO *objNewsRspnc = [objNewsParser getNewsStartingFrom:0 toEndLimit:10];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
for (int i=0; i< [objNewsRspnc.arrNewsData count]; i++) {
[arrListOfNews addObject:[objNewsRspnc.arrNewsData objectAtIndex:i]];
}
isDataLoading = NO;
isBottomLoaderAdded = NO;
[loader stopAnimating];
[loader removeFromSuperview];
[bottomViewforLoader removeFromSuperview];
tbv_ListOfNews.frame = CGRectMake(tbv_ListOfNews.frame.origin.x,   tbv_ListOfNews.frame.origin.y, tbv_ListOfNews.frame.size.width, tbv_ListOfNews.frame.size.height +80);
tbv_ListOfNews.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, tbv_ListOfNews.contentSize.height);
[tbv_ListOfNews reloadData];
    });
});
```

and Here is how i navigate on tablecell's selection:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (bottomViewforLoader != nil) {
tbv_ListOfNews.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 416+APP_DELEGATE.floatExtraHeight) ;
[bottomViewforLoader removeFromSuperview];
}
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
NewsDetailViewController *obj_DetailNews = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
NSLog(@"indexPath.row:%d,arrListOfNews(number of object:%d)  ",indexPath.row,[arrListOfNews count]);
obj_DetailNews.obj_newsDetail = [arrListOfNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[APP_DELEGATE.navController pushViewController:obj_DetailNews animated:YES];
}
```

any help on how to suspend dispatch_get_global_queue ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot suspend/resume the global concurrent queues.  Furthermore, the code you've posted appears to execute synchronously. You will not be able to cancel it without modifying it to be be "cancelable" (i.e. `-getNewsStartingFrom:toEndLimit:` will need to check a variable somewhere indicating cancellation and voluntarily stop itself.) I don't know if you own `NewsResponseBO` or not, but just off the top of my head, this sound like a good job for `NSURLConnection` and a concurrent `NSOperation` owing to `NSOperationQueue/NSOperation`'s support for cancellation (but note that `NSOperation`s still don't get you hard cancellation).

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758583/is-there-any-way-to-implement-dispatch-cancel/18765522#18765522) for more detail on cancellation of pending dispatch jobs and why hard cancellation isn't possible.